# ACPI BIOS error on boot (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS)

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, acpi

I've been having issues with printing, so I restarted my Jumper PC,  which usually fixes the issue. However, when the PC booted up, it started loading then I got this error...

```
Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCIO.T
CPU_ADR],  AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
[   0.337997] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS,  During name lookup/catalog (201908
16/psobject-220)
[   1.246263] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

BugBox vl.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commns.

(Initramfs)
```

...popped up. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> brought up a screen to recover, but it sent me right back to the same error.

[image: img]

Comment: Did you try booting a previous kernel (under the advanced options in the grub menu)? Or maybe recovery mode would help.  then run sudo upate-initramfs